# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/foo.php

Tags: php, mysqli, xampp

It appears that I am unable to connect to the sqli server.
I'm running XAMPP on arch.
I've tried uncommenting `extension=mysqli` under `/etc/php/php.ini` but that doesn't seem to be doing anything. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$serverName = "localhost";
$userName = "root";
$userpwd = "";
$dbName = "databaseName";

$conn = mysqli_connect($serverName, $userName, $userpwd, $dbName);

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    die("Connection Failed!" . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the full error message and exception stack trace?

Comment: @Phil i don't think it's necessary, the message is already full and the error is thrown from mysqli_connect

Comment: @YourCommonSense ah, it's the socket path. I was thinking there was more to this mystery